# SEOstats API SEMrush keyword query methods?

Tags: php, seo, keyword, sem

I'm using SEOstats API (https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats).

With the SEMrush methods, how do you get keyword data--specifically how to you write the query--where does the keyword go?

I have no problems using the SEMrush methods (or any other methods) of the API when the only parameter is the URL. Just don't know where to put keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you misunderstood [SEOstats' documentation](https://github.com/eyecatchup/SEOstats#seostats-semrush-methods), as well as [SEMruch's free organic keyword reports](http://www.semrush.com/features.html#/keywords).

There is no way to request data for specific, user-defined keywords with the public SEMrush API. Instead, they provide a list of relavant keywords related to a specific URL (eg *"to find long-tail keywords"*).

So, you can feed `$SEOstats->SEMRush()->getOrganicKeywords()` with a URL, and get relevant keyword metrics for that URL in return. And there is no option for user-defined keywords.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I've been digging into the code, and starting to understand it. And Thanks again for the api. Linked to your site at the bottom of my page.